# Return nested alias for linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, expression-trees

I have the following Linq Expression

```
var tooDeep = shoppers
    .Where(x => x.Cart.CartSuppliers.First().Name == "Supplier1")
    .ToList();
```

I need to turn the name part into the following string.

```
x.Cart.CartSuppliers.Name
```

As part of this I turned the Expression into a string and then split on the . and removed the First() argument. However, when I get to CartSuppliers this returns a Suppliers[] array. Is there a way to get the single type from this. eg. I need to get a Supplier back.

**Update: Got it to work**

```
var fullName = m.ToString().Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
// this supports the "deep graph" name - "Product.Address.City"
var fixedName = fullName.Skip(1).Take(fullName.Length - 1)
.Where(x => x != "First()")
.Select(x => System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(x, @"\[[0-9]+\]",""))
.ToArray();
```

with this:

```
var prop = property.PropertyType.HasElementType ? property.PropertyType.GetElementType()  property.PropertyType;
```

which enabled be to find the individual type from an array.

Thanks

Comment: sorry, you lost me on this line: I need to turn the name part into the following string. x.Cart.CartSuppliers.Name

Answer (score 1):

```
firstSupplierWithNeededName = shoppers
    .SelectMany(s => s.Cart.CartSuppliers)
    .First(s => s.Name == "Supplier1");
```

But also look into using FirstOrDefault or Single if it has to return just one.

Comment: I'm talking about parsing expression trees. I know the query can be written other ways but thats not the point.

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your question?